# Locked Caching or Simple Cache with locking

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

Our e-commerce application built on ATG, has provision whereby multiple users can update the same Order. Since the cache mode for Order is `Simple` - this has resulted in large number of `ConcurrentUpdateException` and `InvalidVersionException`.  We were considering `locked` cache mode, however are skeptical about using locked caching as the Orders are being updated very frequently and locking might result in deadlocks and have its own performance implications.

Is there a way we can continue using simple cache mode and minimize the occurances of ConcurrentUpdateException and InvalidVersionException?

Answer (score 3):

My experience has been that you have to use locked caching with orders on any medium to high volume ATG websites.. Also,  remember that the end-user experience is bad when this happens as they either get an error message (if the error handling is good) or they get something like an "internal server error" error.

The reason I believe you need to use locked caching for order is:

1. You can't guarantee that a user has not got multiple sessions open at the same time which are updating the shopping cart (which is just an incomplete Order).  I have also seen examples where customers share their logins with family members etc and then wonder why all these items keep magically appearing in their shopping cart.
2. There are a number of processes which update the order including things like scenarios and customer service agents using the CSC module.
3. You could have code which updates orders in a non-safe way.

Some things which might help include:

- Always use the `OrderManager` to load/update an order. Sounds obvious but I have seen a lot of updating orders via the repository.
- Make sure that any updates are inside a transaction block.
- Try to consolidate any background processes which might update orders to run on a small subset of your ATG instances (this will help reduce concurrency)

The ATG [help](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1005lockedcaching01.html) has this to say about it:

> A multi-server application might require locked caching, where only one Oracle ATG Web Commerce instance at a time has write access to the cached data of a given item type. You can use locked caching to prevent multiple servers from trying to update the same item simultaneously—for example, Commerce order items, which can be updated by customers on an external-facing server and by customer service agents on an internal-facing server. By restricting write access, locked caching ensures a consistent view of cached data among all Oracle ATG Web Commerce instances.

That said converting to locked caching will most certainly require performance testing and tuning of the order repository caches.  It can and does result in deadlocks (seen that many times) but if configured correctly the deadlocks are infrequent.

Not sure what version of ATG you are using but for 10.2 there is a good explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s0709maintainingitemconcurrencywithth01.html) of how you can get everything "in sync".

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a Best Practices approach that was recommended in Legacy ATG Community long time ago. Just pasting it here.

When you are using the Order object with synchronization and transactions, there is a specific usage pattern that is critical to follow. Not following the expected pattern can lead to unnecessary ConcurrentUpdateExceptions, InvalidVersionExceptions, and deadlocks. The following sequence must be strictly adhered to in your code:

1. Obtain local-lock on profile ID.
2. Begin Transaction
3. Synchronize on Order
4. Perform ALL modifications to the order object.
5. Call OrderManager.updateOrder.
6. End Synchronization
7. End Transaction.
8. Release local-lock on profile ID.

Steps 1, 2, 7, 8 are done for you in the beforeSet() and afterSet() methods for ATG form handlers where order updates are expected. These include form handlers that extend PurchaseProcessFormHandler and OrderModifierFormHandler (deprecated). If your code accesses/modifies the order outside of a PurchaseProcessFormHandler, it will likely need to obtain the local-lock manually. The lock fetching can be done using the TransactionLockService.

So, if you have extended an ATG form handler based on PurchaseProcessFormHandler, and have written custom code in a handleXXX() method that updates an order, your code should look like:

```
synchronized( order )
{
  // Do order updates
  orderManager.updateOrder( order );
}
```

If you have written custom code updating an order outside of a PurchaseProcessFormHandler (e.g. CouponFormHandler, droplet, pipeline servlet, fulfillment-related), your code should look like:

```
ClientLockManager lockManager = getLocalLockManager(); // Should be configured as /atg/commerce/order/LocalLockManager
boolean acquireLock = false;
try
{
  acquireLock = !lockManager.hasWriteLock( profileId, Thread.currentThread() );
  if ( acquireLock )
    lockManager.acquireWriteLock( profileId, Thread.currentThread() );

  TransactionDemarcation td = new TransactionDemarcation();
  td.begin( transactionManager );
  boolean shouldRollback = false;
  try
  {
    synchronized( order )
    {
      // do order updates
      orderManager.updateOrder( order );
    }
  }
  catch ( ... e )
  {
    shouldRollback = true;
    throw e;
  }
  finally
  {
    try
    {
      td.end( shouldRollback );
    }
    catch ( Throwable th )
    {
      logError( th );
    }
  }
}
finally
{
  try
  {
    if ( acquireLock )
      lockManager.releaseWriteLock( profileId, Thread.currentThread(), true );
  }
  catch( Throwable th )
  {
    logError( th );
  }
}
```

This pattern is only useful to prevent ConcurrentUpdateExceptions, InvalidVersionExceptions, and deadlocks when multiple threads attempt to update the same order on the *same* ATG instance. This should be adequate for most situations on a commerce site since session stickiness will confine updates to the same order to the same ATG instance.

Comment: Actually, no. This 'solution', coming from ATG themselves, does fix the issue of concurrent updates. BUT, if you had an outdated order in memory when you enter this locking, you'll still get an ConcurrentUpdateException/InvalidVersionException. So while this is good, also make sure you do invalidate the order & flush it from caches _after_ gaining locks.